# Keycloak: Prevent client from logging in specific user

Tags: keycloak

Is it possible in keycloak to prevent the `account` client from logging in a specific user? I have a user that is only supposed to log in via the admin-cli endpoints, but it is in the same realm as the account client.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove the

*default-roles-<realm-name>* role

for this user. This will remove the effective roles for the *account* client role
[image]